# "No package ID was found in Dev Hub for package ID: <ID>"

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, beta-managed-package

Getting "*No package ID was found in Dev Hub for package ID:* "

When trying to execute.

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p "Alias" -d force-app --wait 10 --installationkeybypass -a "Name" -n "Vnumber" --codecoverage -f config/project-scratch-def.json --json
```

Before I updated SFDC CLI to latest version this command was working fine

Comment: Which version are you using? If the issue persists, I would suggest attempting to downgrade to a previous version. I've had to resort to this solution in the past.

Comment: I am using @salesforce/cli/2.7.11 win32-x64 node-v18.15.0 Which version should i downgrade to. Any idea ?

Comment: Installed version sfdx-cli/7.200.7 win32-x64 node-v18.15.0 still the issue remains same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options:

1. Have you created the package?  Before you can run `force:package:version:create`, you must run `force:package:create`.
2. Assuming you have previously created the package, check if your package alias exists in your `sfdx-project.json`, in the `packageAliases` section of the file.  It should look something like this, where `"Alias"` matches your `-p` argument:

```
      "packageAliases": {
        "Alias": "0Ho5a0000000001AAA",
      }
```

if that is missing, see if you can recover it from your source code control.  You might also be able to query the `MetadataPackage` object in your Dev Hub org to recover the Id.

3. Make sure that your DevHub is set correctly. When you run `sfdx force:org:list`, one of the entries should show `(D)` to the left of the alias, indicating it is your DevHub.  If this is pointing to the wrong org, you could get the error you are seeing.  It should be pointing to the same (Prod or Developer) org that was used when you created the package with `force:package:create`.  If it is wrong, you can set it using `sfdx config:set defaultdevhubusername=DevHubAlias`.  Alternatively, you can specify it in your package version create command, by adding `-v DevHubAlias` to the command.

**N.B.**:  I've answered using traditional `sfdx`-style commands as that what you use in your question, however, these are being deprecated.  I recommend you [Migrate to the New sf-Style commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_migrate.htm).

Comment: Issue solved. Many thanks for you help. This line helped me solve the problem "It should be pointing to the same (Prod or Developer) org that was used when you created the package with force:package:create"

Comment: Where can i set  postInstallClass, apiAccessLevel for my managed package. ?

Comment: @shamikh You can probably find the answers you want in the [Second-Gen Managed Packing Dev Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_customize_installs.htm); if you need additional help you should start a new question.

Comment: I created this issue here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/411777/where-can-i-set-postinstallclass-apiaccesslevel-for-my-managed-package?noredirect=1#comment589702_411777